# Is OSGi production ready?

Tags: java, osgi

I've recently discovered OSGi and it seems very promising. I would like to ask people that already uses OSGi's implementations, to know if they are production ready. Do they provide the features generally required in production environment? I've read there are many implementations, but I've only looked at Apache Felix.

Thanks

Comment: eclipse is OSGi based. Draw your own conclusions on that fact.

Comment: @FrVaBe Eclipse is Java based. Draw your own conclusions from *that* fact.

Comment: @Neil Bartlett :-) well played (I am native german speaking and hope this is the correct translation for "gut gekontert")

Comment: Another example of serious software based on OSGi is the Adobe CQ5 family of web content management and digital marketing products, which are based on Apache Felix and Apache Sling (a web framework built on OSGi).

Comment: And most JEE App servers, it does not get more ready than this

Comment: Just was reminded by [this](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2012/06/27/top-10-eclipse-juno-features/) blog post that eclipse is OSGi based since 8 years.

Comment: OSGi can be a real pain in production. For example, OSGi caches can become corrupt and when that happens, the app won't run. For this reason, if your client is an OSGi app, every user will need their own cache so that when (not if) the cache becomes corrupt, it only affects one user at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OSGi is definately ready for production. Almost all big Java EE servers have switched to OSGi for their core. The bigger question is if your development team and your projects are already ready for OSGi. Most developers do not yet have solid OSGi experience so make sure the developers are trained well. If you have existing projects it can be a lot of effort to convert them to OSGi. (Depends a bit how well designed they are. Well designed loosely coupled systems typically can be ported relatively easily).

Felix is a good choice as OSGi framework. I would recommend to use it together with [Apache Karaf](http://karaf.apache.org/). It adds a lot of interesting functionality to Felix.

Answer (score 3):

OSGi is production ready. There are many production systems in the enterprise and embedded domain. Many of the Java Application Servers have an OSGi Core. The Eclipse IDE is OSGi based. Next to Felix there are other Open Source implementations (Eclipse Equinox and Knopflerfish) and commercial implementation from ProSyst.

Answer (score 1):

OSGi delivers what it specifies and there are production-quality systems available. However, I would add a caveat: making the *bundle hot-swapping* dream come true requires close collaboration from the programmer and is quite easy to break.

Comment: Which implementation is mostly used in production environment , today? What do you mean by bundle hot-swapping?

Comment: I mean unloading a bundile at runtime and installing an updated version of the same bundle, while the rest of the system keeps on going.

Comment: @MickaelMarrache: Both Equinox and Felix are **very** widely used, but it's impossible to say exactly how widely because they are both open source and freely downloadable. Either of them would be an excellent choice. Knopflerfish is another excellent choice which is also widely used, though more often in the embedded market such as in photocopiers, cars etc.

Comment: @NeilBartlett It is an honor to hear from you :)

Comment: @NeilBartlett Just reading your book :) Thanks for your work. I think I'll start with Apache Felix at first...

Answer (score 1):

OSGi has been production ready for a long time, although new and sometimes experimental features are added all the time, so you should ask yourself this question for individual parts of OSGi. The basics like Core and Declarative Services are rock solid.